# Getting 250 OK status Delivered from SendGrid, but the email never ends up in the mailbox

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

```
function sendEmailVerification(username, email, destination, response, cb){

    // create a random number
    var email_url = security.createEmailToken(username, email);

    // create a new URL for the verify call that will go into the email
    link=PROTOCOL+"://"+destination+"/verify?token="+email_url;

//      to : request.query.to,
   var verifyEmail = new sendgrid.Email();
    verifyEmail.addTo(email);
    verifyEmail.setSubject('Verify your email with example.com.');
    verifyEmail.setFrom('verify@example.com');
    verifyEmail.setText(link);
    verifyEmail.setHtml(link);

    verifyEmail.addFilter('templates', 'enable', 1);
    verifyEmail.addFilter('templates', 'template_id', '3cf3g721-4a31-4fd1-a862-408707e18c96');

    logger.debug("send: mail options for user: " + JSON.stringify(verifyEmail));

    // use the smtp transport to send the email
    sendgrid.send(verifyEmail, function(error, resp) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error(error);
            response.status(500).send("A backend email send error occurred.");
            response.end();
        } else {
            logger.debug("Message sent: " + resp.message);
            response.status(200).send("email sent");
        }
        cb();
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems the client service is not accepting my emails. Is it a problem with the headers? I am attempting to send a verification email with a SendGrid template.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and thank you ahead of time!

Comment: You mean you get a 200 OK response from the API right? Not 250 or 205? Additionally has your account been provisioned by SendGrid?

Comment: @MartynDavies I get a 250 OK when I go to the email activity tab, and it says it was delivered. I have recently found out that I am only having trouble mailing to .edu domains. I think it has to do with them blocking the port that I am sending the mail on. Looking into how to change the send port using the node module.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked your Email Activity on your SendGrid account?

There's two big steps to mail delivery: You passing the message to SendGrid (the 200 OK Martyn is talking about), and SendGrid attempting to deliver the message for you (ideally, the 250 Delivered event).

If you're getting a 250 Delivered event, but not seeing it on the recipient side, that means the mail server is accepting the message from SendGrid, but not giving it to the recipient for some reason. Unfortunately, SendGrid can't see any further than the Delivered event, so you'd have to talk to the mail admin of the receiving server to see what's happened with the message.

Comment: Yes, it seems to only happen with .edu/educations domains. I can send email successfully to other domains easily.

Comment: @DanaGriffin The 250 response is from the receiving server which means they accepted it, they may not decide to send it on at that stage. I would recommend consuming some data via our Event Webhook to check for further events and possibly the root cause of the issue on their end.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error and turned out GMail was sending my messages to Spam and Trash.